# How to generate a random double between 0 and a variable in c++

Tags: c++, random

Is there a way of generating a random double between 0 and a variable. The variable is of type double and changes each time the code is run so the range in which the number can be chosen from can vary, but it will always be less than 1. 
I tried to generate a number and cast it to a `double` but that didn't work.

Comment: Use `drand48` function.

Comment: Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::uniform_real_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

template <typename T>
T RandomFromRange(T low, T high){
    std::random_device random_device;
    std::mt19937 engine{random_device()};
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dist(low, high);
    return dist(engine);
}


int main(){

  double changing_var;
  std::cout << RandomFromRange<double>(0,changing_var) << '\n';
  std::cout << RandomFromRange<double>(0,changing_var) << '\n';
  std::cout << RandomFromRange<double>(0,changing_var) << '\n';
}
```